# Will Dolphin emulator run (smoothly) on this machine?

Tags: specifications, dolphin-emulator

[Product](http://ncix.com/products/?sku=60545&vpn=ZBOX-ID41-U&manufacture=Zotac)

Specs:

- Intel NM10 Express chipset with an Intel [Atom D525](http://ark.intel.com/products/49490/Intel-Atom-processor-D525-1M-Cache-1_80-GHz) (dual-core, 1.8 GHz)

I think the most I can put in there for RAM is 4 GB. (They don't make 8 GB SoDIMM do they?)

The Dolphin site is pretty [vague about requirements](http://dolphin-emulator.com/system-requirements.html):

- Windows XP or higher, or Linux, or OS/X Intel
- Fast CPU with SSE2.
- GPU with Pixel Shader 2.0 or greater. Some integrated graphics chips work but it depends on the model (and only with DirectX 9).

I'm trying to make a light-weight quiet little machine for streaming video and playing emulators, and I'm trying to figure out the minimum requirements I will need to do what I want.

I know I'm not supposed to ask for product recommendations here, so if you could just advise the minimum requirements in terms of CPU, graphics card, and RAM, that would be helpful.

---

What about the [ZOTAC 2nd Gen Intel Core i3-2330M Mini PC](http://www.futureshop.ca/en-CA/product/zotac-zotac-2nd-gen-intel-core-i3-2330m-mini-pc-zbox-id82-u-zbox-id82-u/10217237.aspx?path=0f83530d14cbc712da95552b82d0d971en02)?

- Intel Core i3 2330M dual core processor
- Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: The Atom D525 supports at most 4GB. Even if you had a 8GB SoDIMM it would not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the FAQ on the official Dolphin website: https://dolphin-emu.org/docs/faq/

The link you posted is to an old unofficial third party website not affiliated with Dolphin Team.

As for your question that PC will likely not not run games in Dolphin well. A powerful CPU is required for full speed emulation.

Comment: I swear I see you anywhere Dolphin gets mentioned. Heck, it looks like you made a SE account just to answer this question!

Answer (score 7):

It won't work.

It barely works on my low-end i3 with low-end GeForce.
After my upgrade to the GeForce GT260 made it run at a decent speed, but there is no way that it would work smoothly on an Atom with a GMA3050 as a GPU.